# p:selectOneButton default value

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a simple use case with `p:selectOneButton`.

I basically want one option to be checked=true but allow users to change. I tried different combinations of only having value set for one but no change.
Pseudo code below:

```
<p:selectOneButton id="options" value="#{buttonBean.number}">
<f:selectItem default="true" itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />
</p:selectOneButton>
```

I tried javascript to no avail, not that I expected it to work since I'm not updating it on the server side...

```
document.getElementById('options:0').checked = true;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
<f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"/>
```

Or, what I would do, initialize `number` in `buttonBean` `@PostConstruct` method:

```
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    number = 1;
}
```

Comment: Gosh. Feel pretty silly now I thought I started out trying with a default value in the bean but I must have screwed that up somehow :-)

noSelectionOption does not work with this component afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Set the number property within your buttonBean to "1". Primefaces will show the item that corresponds to the value as default and change it if you select another item.

Bean:

```
private String number = "1";
```

To update the view according to changes you can additionally place a listener to update the form:

```
<h:form id="form-id">
....
<p:selectOneButton id="options" value="#{buttonBean.number}">
<f:selectItem default="true" itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />
<p:ajax update=":form-id"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
```

This would allow you to use the button to trigger UI logic, like showing or hiding fields.

Comment: How is this (fundamentally) different from the other answesr?

Answer (score -1):

Because i call mine after postconstruct i initialised in getter. Situations differ so please test. We do not always initialize every value in postconstruct. You can then then run another setMethod to set values from the selectOneButton after the user submits the request, I am actually doing that in my code.

```
public String getNumber () {
  number = "10"; // default value
  methodThatInitializesDefaults(); // alternatively 
  return number;
}
```